# flash actionscript 1.0, load external swf file to parent swf file

Tags: flash

i'm building a website using flash. i have a external swf file that i want to import into my website. i thought this would be an easy task but for some reason when i load the movie, it flickers. my website (parent swf) was build using 1.0. The external form swf was build using 3.0. any thoughts?

My approach:

```
1.create an empty movie clip called mcForm
2.go to the mc clip page i want to pull the external movie into 
3. within my actions layer, I call the following function
loadMovie("main.swf", mcForm);
```

If i write:

```
LoadMovieNum("main.swf",0);
```

then the my main.swf opens correctly but closes the parent swf file. I wan the main.swf file to be embeded within the parent file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to load an ActionScript 3 movie into an ActionScript 1 or 2 movie. The reason is that AS3 is processed by the *ActionScript Virtual Machine 2` (AVM2), while AS1 and AS2 are processed by AVM1. As such, when you have a AVM1 movie and try to load something that was targetted for AVM2, everything that is unsupported (as such, nearly everything) will be lost. As the AVM2 is able to execute AVM1 code however, the reverse (i.e. loading AS1/2 videos into AS3) is possible.

The only exception to this is when the movie is actually scriptless, i.e. a simple (“stupid”) animation.

Comment: Thanks! i just embeded an old form built in actionscript 1.0 and LoadMovieNum("main.swf",0); worked. but now i have to figure out how to postion it on the page. thanks for your help!